# bootstrap thumbnail images same size

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap thumbnail where each contain an image and a heading.
The problem is that images are not same size, and I want them to be displayed having an equal size to make the thumbnails have the same dimensions. I am using angular **ng-repeat** to get a list of countries with their images and names.

```
<style>
  .thumbnail:hover{
    background: #f7f7f7;
  }
 .thumbnail img{
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 98px;
    width: 137px;
    border:solid 1px #cccccc;
  }
</style>
<div class="row">
  <div ng-repeat="team in $ctrl.teams">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
       <a href="">
        <img ng-src="{{team.imgpath}}"  alt="team"/>
        <div class="caption text-center">
          <h4>{{team.name}}</h4>
        </div>
       </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I set fixed values for height and width, however, the images are not displayed with same size since they are not originally having the same sizes.

What can I do to keep the content responsive using bootstrap and let the images be displayed with same size?

Comment: If you use angularjs, **ng-repeat** is used to display the same structure with different content, here I'm getting an array of countries and for each country I display its content in a thumbnail. The problem the img of the countries have different sizes, even if I am setting fixed height and width, bootstrap do not display them equal.

Comment: In your example, you have pic1 [height: 125, width: 125], pic2 [height: 250, width: 250], where width = height. My pics don't have width = height. I have pic1 [height: 393, width: 550] and pic2 [height: 369, width: 550]. Mostly same width with different height.

Comment: I've created another fiddle, hope this helps https://jsfiddle.net/y12rgpdL/

Comment: @Hardik there's no real reason to add extra markup to fix the problem, use specificity and all is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap uses two classes to target thumbnail images:

`.thumbnail img` and `.thumbnail a > img`

You need to use the one with the higher specificity (`.thumbnail a > img`) so your styles don't get overwritten.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.thumbnail:hover {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.thumbnail a > img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 98px;
  width: 137px;
  border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/125x70" alt="team">
          <div class="caption text-center">
            <h4>{{team.name}}</h4>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/250x140" alt="team">
          <div class="caption text-center">
            <h4>{{team.name}}</h4>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/125x70" alt="team">
          <div class="caption text-center">
            <h4>{{team.name}}</h4>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/75x25" alt="team">
          <div class="caption text-center">
            <h4>{{team.name}}</h4>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/125x70" alt="team">
          <div class="caption text-center">
            <h4>{{team.name}}</h4>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/125x70" alt="team">
          <div class="caption text-center">
            <h4>{{team.name}}</h4>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect solution :)

Comment: Great! Note I deleted my comments as they were based on an error I caused and are no longer valid.

Comment: Thanks @hungerstar! :) will note this